# jQuery Autocomplete, different source depending on what character was entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have textbox to which I added autocomplete. But this is the issue, I want to be able to use a different value from the object depending if parenthesis is entered or not.The issue is that I need to create something like `State(County)`. I pick the State (this part works OK), but then I need to pick the County after a `(` is entered, it doesn't do anything, no error or nothing.[image]

[image]

This is my code:

```
  $(function() {
     $("document").ready(function() {

    var states = [
        { 'state': "New York", 'county': '1' },
        { 'state': "New York", 'county': '1a' },
        { 'state': "New York", 'county': '1b' },
        { 'state': "Florida", 'county': '2' },
        { 'state': "Florida", 'county': '2a' },
        { 'state': "Florida", 'county': '2b' },
        { 'state': "Florida", 'county': '3' },
        { 'state': "Alaska", 'county': '4' },
        { 'state': "Alaska", 'county': '5' },
        { 'state': "Hawaii", 'county': '6' },
        { 'state': "Hawaii", 'county': '7' },
        { 'state': "Maine", 'county': '8' },
        { 'state': "Maine", 'county': '9' },
        { 'state': "Maine", 'county': '10' }
    ];
function split(val) {
  return val.split(/,\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
  return split(term).pop();
}

$('#text').on('keypress', function(e) {
  theKeyCode = e.which;

  // if (e.which !== 40) { // I tried this too ------------
  if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) !== '(') { // Just trying something different

    $(e.target)
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        source: function(request, response) {
          var lastEntry = extractLast(request.term);
          var filteredArray = $.map(states, function(item) {
            if (item.state.indexOf(lastEntry) === 0) {
              return item.state;

            } else {
              return null;
            }
          });
          response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(filteredArray, lastEntry));
        },
        focus: function() {
          return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
          var terms = split(this.value);
          terms.pop();
          terms.push(ui.item.value);
          terms.push("");
          this.value = terms.join("");

          return false;
        }
      }).on("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB /** && $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active **/ ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return;
        }
        var newY = $(this).textareaHelper('caretPos').top + (parseInt($(this).css('font-size'), 10) * 1.5);
        var newX = $(this).textareaHelper('caretPos').left;
        var posString = "left+" + newX + "px top+" + newY + "px";
        $(this).autocomplete("option", "position", {
          my: "left top",
          at: posString
        });
      });
  } else {

    console.log(e.which); //This shows the right e.which
    $('#text').autocomplete("destroy"); // Just experimenting. It doesn't work with or without it
    $(e.target)
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        source: function(request, response) {
          var lastEntry = extractLast(request.term);
          var filteredArray = $.map(states, function(item) {
            if (item.county.indexOf(lastEntry) === 0) {
              return item.county;
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          });
          response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(filteredArray, lastEntry));
        },
        focus: function() {
          return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
          var terms = split(this.value);
          terms.pop();
          terms.push(ui.item.value);
          terms.push("");
          this.value = terms.join("), ");
          return false;
        }
      }).on("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return;
        }
        var newY = $(this).textareaHelper('caretPos').top + (parseInt($(this).css('font-size'), 10) * 1.5);
        var newX = $(this).textareaHelper('caretPos').left;
        var posString = "left+" + newX + "px top+" + newY + "px";
        $(this).autocomplete("option", "position", {
          my: "left top",
          at: posString
        });
      });
  } //e.preventDefault();
});



 });
});
```

I know there are some issues here, like when I enter the state name, the same entry shows several times, but I'll deal with that later, I just want to be sure that what I'm trying to do is possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ugaybw9r/

Comment: Very neat, and pretty close, but it seems to work only once. There will be multiple states entered in the same textbox. I should probably have mentioned that on my initial question. Thanks.